# oracle forms 6i frm-40301 query caused no records to be retrieved

Tags: oracle, forms

I have created sales master and sales detail (master/detail) relationship form.
I have entered record and saved it ...
Through another form, i hv updated few fields of sales_master table .. see below example

During data entry - Like ... Sal_OrdStatus = 'Open'   and CashRcvd_Status='P'
Updating these fields through payment form Sal_OrdStatus = 'Closed' and CashRcvd_Status='R'

After this, when I am entering/execute those records where both fields are updated

then see below error even record is available in the database/table
frm-40301 query caused no records to be retrieved, re-enter
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEOjv.png)
Please advise solution/ guideline

Thanks
Javed Akram

Answer (score 0):

Querying data block won't return anything if there are no rows in the table at all, or if **condition you set** prevents any rows to be retrieved.

As some rows obviously exist (you updated them, not deleted), then it is the latter.

Use `get_block_property` built in and its `last_query` property (you can try `default_where` as well) to see which query was really executed; you'll see the `where` clause, and that should help you find the culprit. Once you know it, you'll be able to fix it.